# Remote NiFi input ports are not exposed

Tags: dataflow, apache-nifi

I'm learning Apache NiFi. I'm working on a simple site-to-site data flow. On one side, I have a single node NiFi and on the other side, I have two node NiFi cluster. The issue that I'm facing is, (on the single node instance)when I connect a `GetFile` processor with a `Remote Process Group`(Two node NiFi cluster), the connection details asks me to select the `Input Port` name of the Remote Cluster. However, in the drop down list, my remote cluster's input port name is not displayed.

I have given the correct URL of the remote NiFi cluster. the single node instance is supposed to talk with the remote cluster to get the port details and port names, right? Then why is it now showing my input port?

Comment: Are the input ports on the cluster at the root group level (top-level canvas)? You can't do site-to-site directly to ports that are with in lower level process groups. The ports also have to be started at some point for the RPG to pick them up.

Comment: Are the NiFi instances secured? If so, you'll need to explicitly authorize the client instance to be allowed to send and receive data from the desired ports.

Comment: Yes. They are secured and at top level in canvas. The thing is it detects the other two input ports that were created two weeks ago.

Comment: If it is finding some of the ports and not others it sounds like a permission problem. Did you create the policy on each of your input ports for "receive data via site-to-site" ?

Comment: How to do that? I tried accessing the "Policy" tool from the dropdown option. However it only has user details.

Comment: While the port is selected on the canvas, click the tool icon in the palette on the left. This blog post covers the steps to setup secure site-to-site http://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/30/apache-nifi-1.0.0-secure-site-to-site

Comment: Thank you so much, man. You should have written it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a secure setup, there are two policies that need to be created. One is a global policy that allows the Remote Process Group to ask the other NiFi for information about the nodes/node, this is called "retrieve site-to-site details", the other is a policy on each port that allows data to be sent to it, this is called "receive data via site-to-site".

This blog post explains how to configure secure site-to-site in more detail:
http://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/30/apache-nifi-1.0.0-secure-site-to-site